# C# Visual Studio - Implementing user authentication using text files

Tags: c#, console-application

Using visual studio 2013 and Console Application.

My question, How to I make something like this: I have a programm. I want the programm to check if there is a file called Usernames.txt, If there is,do nothing and if there is not, Create a new one.

Now when that Is done, I want the console to ask the person to enter a username, When the person does it, I want the programm to check if the file called: Usernames.txt contains that same username that the person entered, If yes, Then tell the person: This username already exists, Pick a new one. If not then add it to the file and continue on to ask for a password and so on.

This is what I got so far and I don't know what to do next:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Username: ");
            string uCreation = Console.ReadLine();
            bool exists = false;
            foreach (string lines in File.ReadAllLines("Usernames.txt"))
            {
                if (lines == uCreation)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Username already exists!");
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!exists)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"Usernames.txt", uCreation + Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Am I on the right track? I have no idea D= If anybody could help out with some solutions that would be sweet!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: that piece of code will do what the second part of your question describes. As for the first part, there is the `File.Exists()` function to check whether a file exists on disk or not.

Comment: I got the exists part figured out...finally lol. I am not getting a error, But what is happening is that If I run the programm, Input my username, lets say its: Karl, Then it adds it to the the txt file, But when I run it again, And type the username exactly the same, It won't tell me there is a username like this already exsisting.

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me. I made it an infinite loop and added file checking and it seems to work without any modification to the checking logic: [check it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tegyyi)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify this code to suit your requirements.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"c:\Usernames.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File already exists.I am doing nothing.Tadaaaaaaaaaa !!!");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string sContinue = "yes";
                HashSet<string> sUserNames = new HashSet<string>();
                while (sContinue.Equals("yes"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter username:");
                    string sUserName = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (!sUserNames.Contains(sUserName))
                    {
                        sUserNames.Add(sUserName);
                        using (StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Usernames.txt", true))
                            oWriter.WriteLine(sUserName);

                        Console.WriteLine("Username {0} was added.Enter yes to continue or no to exit", sUserName);
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Username {0} exists.Enter yes to add new username or no to exit", sUserName);
                    sContinue = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

[image: Usernames.txt]

Comment: The thing is, I can't figure it out so that lets say, When the username is available, It will write it into the file and continue on with asking the user a password. If the username is not available I want it to ask for a new username as long as the user enters an available username, Then continue to ask for a password.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution :**

```
static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Usernames.txt";
        if (File.Exists(path))
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists. Exiting the application...");
        else
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string IsContinue = "Y";
            while (IsContinue.Equals("Y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the username --");
                string userName = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!list.Contains(userName))
                {
                    list.Add(userName);
                    File.AppendAllText(path, userName + Environment.NewLine);

                    Console.WriteLine("Success...! Continue (Y/N) ?", userName);
                    IsContinue = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} already exists. Choose a new Username again.\n", userName);
            }
        }
    }
```

....................................
 [image]

Comment: The thing is, I can't figure it out so that lets say, When the username is available, It will write it into the file and continue on with asking the user a password. If the username is not available I want it to ask for a new username as long as the user enters an available username, Then continue to ask for a password.

Comment: The problem lies in your original query itself. You never mentioned that you want to implement the **user authentication using text files** (this shoud be the proper question).
The answers given by us are exactly what you asked for.

You should first go and edit your question to your proper requirement.

Comment: The best way to implement the user authentication is using the databases instead of using text files. If you are a very beginner learner or don't know how to use a database, then you may go for text files.

Comment: I realized it myself aswell and I edited it, A bit late for that... And yes I am a begginner and never used the database method. And I still for the love of god cannot figure it out for the code to continue to ask for a password. Next time I will not make a mistake like that.